# magento :custom ajax call on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

i added custom.js to my product edit page

i have added attribute with id "getdata" now there is another file where value show based on what user select in dropdown

i need to do ajax call to other page with value of dropddown , calling ajax is simple i want to use magento built in way of calling ajax url and loader also how can i do it ??

i wrote below code but its now working

```
function myajaxcall(id){
new Ajax.Request('/a.php?id='+id, {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
}
```

what am i missing pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code :

```
    function myajaxcall(id){

new Ajax.Request('a.php?id='+id, {
  method:'get',
  onSuccess: function(data) {
    var response = data.responseText || "no response text";
    alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
  },
  onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
});
}
```